# Error warnings with dbGetQuery() in RJDBC with Oracle

Tags: r, rjdbc

I am using `dbGetQuery()` function to query the Oracle and put results into a data frame in R. I have connected to database successfully, and returned data using `dbGetQuery()` with simple queries. However, I have a query looks like:

```
Query <- paste("With A as (SELECT * from Table A),
          B as (SELECT * from Table B),
          C as (SELECT * from Table C)
          SELECT A.a,B.b,C.c
          FROM C
          LEFT OUTER JOIN A on (...)
          LEFT OUTER JOIN B on (...);")
Data <- dbGetQuery(conn, Query)
```

I have run this query in Oracle and it works well, and returned a table with all data from Table `C` and data from Table `A` and `B` qualified with on statement. When I paste this query to R, and use `dbGetQuery()` function, I got nothing but a error warning saying:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for With Albemarle_Data AS
```

I am wondering if anyone met similar problem before, and would be grateful if I can get any solution from you. Thank you.

Comment: sometime i have to use `dbQuoteIdentifier( conn  , "columname")` and `dbQuoteString( conn  , "char")` to ge tthe good column name and variable value in query or maybe you should use `WITH` instead of `With`

Comment: Thx for your answer, I have changed `with` to `WITH` but it does not work. I don't understand `dbQuoteIdentifier( conn , "columname")` and `dbQuoteString( conn , "char")` well after checking the help documatation, would you like to explain how to use it more detailed? Thank you

Comment: something like  `query <- paste0(  "SELECT " ,  dbQuoteIdentifier(conn,"c" )  , "FROM C")` it will surround c with "\ \"